# Using Geocoder in a Functional Test

Tags: 8, testing

I am writing my first test in Drupal 8's API and for some reason, I am unable to geocode.

When I run my code in a controller, it works fine, but when using a test, `$addressCollection` evaluates to false and I get the message 'The geocder returned FALSE'.

```
namespace Drupal\Tests\custom_tests\Functional;

use Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase;

/**
 * Test that Geocoder works
 * Source: https://deninet.com/node/1631
 * 
 * Note: need to have Gecoder: Google Maps configured properly before testing.
 * 
 * @group custom_tests
 */
class GeocoderModuleTest extends BrowserTestBase {

  /**
   * The modules to load to run the test.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public static $modules = [
    'geocoder',
  ];

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    // $this->geocoder = \Drupal::service('geocoder');
    $this->geocoder = $this->container->get('geocoder');

    /* Values tested for */
    $this->staticAddress = 'St Patrick\'s Close, Wood Quay, Dublin 8, Ireland';
    $this->staticCordinates = [
      'longitude' => 53.339529,
      'latitude' => -6.271501,
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Tests the setting form.
   */
  public function testForm() {

    $plugins = array('googlemaps');
    $address = '1 Centennial Square, Victoria, BC V8W 1P6'; // Victoria City Hall

    // $this->geocoder = \Drupal::service('geocoder');
    $addressCollection = $this->geocoder->geocode($address, $plugins);

    if ($addressCollection) {
      $this->assertTrue(TRUE);
      // $coordinates = $addressCollection->first()->getCoordinates();

      // /* Check the longitudes */
      // $this->assertEquals(
      //   $staticCordinates['longitude'], 
      //   $coordinates->getLongitude(), 
      //   'The latitudes didn\'t match',
      //   0.001);

      // /* Check the latitudes */
      // $this->assertEquals(
      //   $staticCordinates['latitude'],
      //   $coordinates->getLatitude(),
      //   'The longitudes didn\'t match', 
      //   0.001);
    } else {
      $this->assertFalse(TRUE, 'The geocder returned FALSE');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't think line cause a php error straight away: $this->staticAddress = 'St Patrick's Close, Wood Quay, Dublin 8, Ireland'; The apostrophe on Patrick's would interfer with your string declaration of that whole address. Or is that just the way its been pasted onto here?

Comment: @Leigh Sorry, yes. I entered an example Address. Editing...